# NPE on unit test using mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I tried to unit test some util class, below :

```
public final class WalletInputValidationUtils {
private WalletInputValidationUtils() {
}

public static boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
    return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
}
```

and this is the test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class WalletInputValidationUtilsTest {
private static final CharSequence DUMMY_EMAIL = "email@gmail.com";

@Test
public void isEmailValidTest1() {
    Assert.assertTrue(isEmailValid(DUMMY_EMAIL));
}
}
```

I got null pointer exception in this line

```
return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
```

this is the stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at kudo.mobile.app.wallet.backwardcompatibility.WalletInputValidationUtils.isEmailValid(WalletInputValidationUtils.java:14)
at kudo.mobile.app.wallet.backwardcompatibility.WalletInputValidationUtilsTest.isEmailValidTest(WalletInputValidationUtilsTest.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:316)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:300)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunne
```

Can anyone help me to fix this ? thanks

Comment: You need to show your stacktrace and also what is the content of this class `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS`.

Comment: @GMsoF update the questions, Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS is actually form android.util package https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns

Comment: Can you write print out on this three object in your method `isEmailValid`: 1) `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` 2) `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email)` 3) `email`

Comment: 1. Nullpointer exception
2. Nullpointer exception
3. "email@gmail.com"
@GMsoF

Comment: Did you try to use PowerMock to mock `Patterns` class? I think you need to share your whole/complete source file, it is either you do the mock wrongly or you import the class wrongly.

Comment: anyway, your stacktrace show your error at `WalletInputValidationUtilsTest.isEmailValidTest`, not `isEmailValidTest1`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help, I found the issue, it's on the different version of mockito used in my local machine and in hosted jenkins. The unit test I wrote is actually passed in server

Answer (score 13):

Just solved it by switching from `Patterns.EMAIL_ADRESS.matcher()` to `PatternsCompat.EMAIL_ADRESS.matcher()`. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting an NPE because `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` was null in my unit tests. Switching to `android.support.v4.util.PatternsCompat` solved that issue

Answer (score 0):

think it should match alike that:

```
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than Mocking Patterns you should get expected output.

Recommend to use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)

Code snippet is below:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Patterns;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void mobileNumber_passedValidNumber_success() {
        assertThat(Patterns.PHONE.matcher("+919895123456").matches()).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void mobileNumber_passedInvalidNumber_error() {
        assertThat(Patterns.PHONE.matcher("+91+9895123456").matches()).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    public void email_passedValidEmail_success() {
        assertThat(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher("android.developer@gmail.com").matches()).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void email_passedInvalidEmail_error() {
        assertThat(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher("android.developer@gmail.com@in").matches()).isFalse();
    }
}
```